# How to handle alert using Selenium python&

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, alert

***When browser redirect me to telegram page, i have an alert(look at the screenshot). How can I cancel It?***

I use this **code**, but i have an error at the second line:

```py
alert = Alert(driver)
alert.dismiss()
```

**Error**:
[image]

**Screenshot** of **alert**, which i try to close:
[image]

Comment: Your error message doesn't correspond to the browser alert you posted a picture of. Please remove the picture of the error message. Rerun your script and capture the error message as text, edit your question, and post the error as text, properly formatted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDK which type this window has. But the easiest solution is just send "enter" to browser and window will be closed.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys

WebElement.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
```

Comment: If you found the answer to your own question and it's working, make sure you mark your answer as the solution so the question doesn't remain unanswered.

Answer (score 2):

It seems `Brower Notification` to me not an alert.
Try with chrome options to disabled the `Brower Notification`

Here are two ways to `disabled` the `browser notifications`.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications" : 2}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),options=chrome_options)
driver.get("specific url")
```

or

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),options=chrome_options)
driver.get("specific url")
```

Comment: Browser Notification is really disappear after i have done, what you said. But this thing, which i want to close, still have a spot

Comment: @AntonioFrank, Can you share the url, to check what's the issue?

Comment: this one https://t.me/kaifustore

Comment: @AntonioFrank: Sorry, I am unable to access the url. May be location access issue.